# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'myurl/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: api, soap, magento-1.9.2

request code 
.............

zzz
                zsw12wd

..............
response .......

    
        
            
                WSDL
                SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://myurl/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Extra content at the end of the document

Answer (score 0):

remove this:

```
$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
$this->_view->renderLayout();
```

from the execute() function inside the controller you are trying to hit.

Is it an adminhtml page or is it front end?

Comment: Admin @dwhalley

Comment: you need to send the Form Key with the request.
Use this: 
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
To get a valid form key and then send it with your request as FORMKEY